# Using SSIS how can you remove a quote from a csv field

Tags: sql, csv, import, ssis

My csv import has just stopped working and upon checking the data coming in I have noticed that the source (out of my control) has the column delimtier i'm using in a field

Normal Data:
"APPLE","Apple iPad","399.99"

Bad Data:
"HP","inch" Screen","150.99"

How can I over come this issue?

Comment: That is badly formatted CSV. It is extremely difficult to cope with CSVs that don't adhere to the standard. You will have to write a bespoke script to handle it.

Comment: What exactly are you using as column delimiter now? If it is a single `"` then what hapens with the comma?

Comment: Agree that you have to edit the CSV before processing, either with script or manually. Easiest way for this one is to remove the quotation marks around strings - ie. quotes on either side of the comma.

Comment: Using " as the delimiter

Comment: In Flat File connection settings do you have (") set as a text qualifier?

Comment: Yes so the normal data in my example works perfectly, the import fails when an extra " is inside the field :(